# How do I get a name of an attribute in the request in string format

Tags: php, laravel

How do I get a name of an attribute in the request, I need to automatically get the name in the string format. for example:

```
$request->some_attribute
```

is there a php way to extract this attribute name to a string?

I want to avoid having to do this

```
    Setting::set($section, 'enable', $request->enable);
    Setting::set($section, 'type', $request->type);
    Setting::set($section, 'must_be_registered', $request->must_be_registered);
```

I want to do this:

```
    Setting::set($section, $request->enable);
    Setting::set($section, $request->type);
    Setting::set($section, $request->must_be_registered);
```

this is how set function looks:

static public function set($section, $key, $value)

I would like to avoid at all having to pass the key which I must hardcode, if I could somehow get in string what I refer with $request-> then I wuold

```
        $setting->section = $section;
        $setting->key = magic_function($request->enable);
        $setting->value = $value;
```

key would now hold the name of attribute and not the value

> "enable", etc

Is it not possible to do this? request already has all the names of the attributes that I sent, I just want to avoid having to type these manually in Controller when I want to save a value into a specific key that is named exactly in blade as I need it to be named in database.

Comment: Do you mean the attribute of an HTML element like a div id?

Comment: I am using Laravel and send a POST request to the Controller with some variables, I can access these with $request->title, etc.. I wonder if there is a way to get the attribute title into a string without me having to hardcode it in the Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand the question, but I think you want this...

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
  echo "$key=$value";
 }
```

Comment: can you check my updated question, I need to be able to extract key name in string but not by looping like that, I need to be able to extract it on key by key basics, not in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you need.  Something you might want to consider, if you don't want to implement code in the loop, is to store the key and/or values in a variable (probably an array) and then just use them when you want them. The loop will store them in a variable for later use.

Comment: I need name of the key, is that possible without looping?

Comment: actually your answer is the solution, I can loop through the request easy and set each key and value accordingly, perfect thank you

Comment: instead of `$_POST` you can use `$request->except('_token')` since are using **Laravel**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you want to do is get the attribute of an HTML tag. For example, for this tag

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="some_value" title="some_title">
```

You know you can fetch the value of it doing `$request->some_name`, but you'd like to access also "some_title" by doing `$request->title`.

This can't be done like that, Laravel can't read the HTML tree like you do in Javascript.

One way to acheive what you want though, is to have some hidden input fields in your form, like so:

That way, you'll be able to access the value in your request by doing `$request->title`.

Comment: Hi Jean, you have not understood me correctly, I will update my question with direct example what I would like to accomplish, please check. I am sure this has nothing to do with laravel, its pure PHP thing and it has to be possible to do, probably with some magic method.